# how do you detect what (site/service/stored procedure) is making call to SQL Server 2005 using the sa login?

Tags: sql-server

i was just wondering if anybody knows how to detect what is calling the sa login on my sql server 2005. I have a stack of websites and i swear i configured these with a different user id and password but my event viewer logs tell me that something is constantly trying to login using the sa credentials. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Usually a SA auth request is an attacker... are they failed attempts? Is your Firewall open to the public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are successfully connected then you can look in sys.dm_exec_connections, this will at least tell you the client_net_address (IP address as reported to Windows).  You can also look at PROGRAM_NAME and HOST_NAME in sys.dm_exec_sessions, but be aware that these are not necessarily populated, and are easy to spoof.

Comment: hi mate, thx for the help, however, doing a select using the "PROGRAM_NAME" and "HOST_NAME" properties of sys.dm_exec_connections tells me that these yield invalid column names in the query result

Comment: Johnny, try sys.dm_exec_sessions  or plain old proc sp_who2

Comment: That's because those columns are in sys.dm_exec_sessions.

Answer (score 5):

run profiler, create a new trace, use event **audit login** and **audit login failed**  you can filter for username sa if you want

see image below

[image]

See also this post by onpnt: [To SA or not to SA](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/to-sa-or-not-to-sa)

you could also use a [Logon Trigger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx) but that will only fire if the authentication is succesful

Comment: Just as an aside, the application name and host name you will see here are the same that sys.dm_exec_sessions uses, and are subject to the same warnings about spoofing.